# Loading an external class folder in eclipse - java

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, class-library, lpsolve

I am trying to use the `LPsolver` on a project I am working on. (it contains both `jar` and `DLL`s).
When I ran it locally it worked (`System.loadLibrary("lpsolver")`)
But now I am trying to upload it to an amazon server which is running tomcat.
I can't get the tomcat server to load class library correctly.
Tried to include it in all kind of different locations and loading it but non seemed to work.

Any idea how I can accomplish it ?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Tried lots of stuff I found on the web, mainly ways to include the class library I need inside the project and not a reference through the local vars.but my project does not seem to recognize it. Also wanted to upload it to my amazon web server ( to system32) but I guess because I use the free version that option is not included...

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: Tried lots of stuff I found on the web, mainly ways to include the class library I need inside the project and not a reference through the local vars.but my project does not seem to recognize it. Also wanted to upload it to my amazon web server ( to system32) but I guess because I use the free version that option is not included...

Comment: It needs to be in the question.